# Traceroute OSX Terminal vs Network Utility

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, traceroute

Why would terminal>traceroute #.#.#.# show different results than using the network utility.app? Here is the first 3 hops. I am connected to PIA VPN but regardless both methods should show the same results I would think.

```
termnial
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
1  10.199.1.1 (10.199.1.1)  42.559 ms  39.696 ms  38.293 ms
2  * * *
3  184-75-211-129.amanah.com (184.75.211.129)  49.639 ms
162.219.176.225 (162.219.176.225)  56.780 ms
dpaall.webexpressmail.net (162.219.179.65)  69.798 ms


netutil.app
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 64 hops max, 72 byte packets
1  10.199.1.1 (10.199.1.1)  41.221 ms  38.355 ms  47.237 ms
2  vl685-c8-10-c6-1.pnj1.choopa.net (209.222.15.225)  41.262 ms  38.674 ms  41.912 ms
3  vl126-br1.pnj1.choopa.net (108.61.92.105)  44.092 ms  36.200 ms  40.407 ms
```

Comment: `traceroute` sends UDP packets, maybe Network Utility sends ICMP, and your VPN treats them differently.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. apple.stackexchange.com or superuser.com would be better places to ask.

Comment: Ah yes, posted to the wrong one. Sorry. Thank you for the suggestion regardless. :)

Comment: You could use `sudo tcpdump -n host 8.8.8.8` to see what you're sending in each case.

Comment: I found a solution and posted it to apple.stackexchange.com/a/379249/4222. @Barmar had the right idea. Thanks for the hint!